# Script to find a patch set between two branches

Tags: git, version-control, graph, git-merge

I'm aware `git merge-base` gets the best common parent for two branches. But how to I get a patch set, which merged, gives me the patch to apply to one of the branches to get it to the poing where the other branch is?

Git development is non-linear, which means you could find many of these patch sets. I'm aiming for one.

The **base case** of this patch set is where no merges occurred whitin the new branch, and the path from the branch HEAD to the common ancestor can be used as the patch set (is also the only one).

The **inductive case** is when a merge is found in this path between the ancestor and the branch HEAD:

1. All commits in the path between HEAD and the *sub-merge* are included.
2. The *sub-merge commit* is included
3. Find the closest sub-ancestor which is child of the ancestor.
4. All commits between this sub-merge and this sub-ancestor are ignored.
5. The shortest patch set between this sub-ancestor and the ancestor is united with this set.
6. If at step 3., not sub-ancestor is found, then include all commits of the branch which is child of the ancestor (merge is with branch which doesn't include our ancestor).

This is a complex operation git already does. Trying to reproduce it to the this patch set is difficult. How does a script look like to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is difficult for me to parse, but it sounds a lot like you are just asking how `git rebase` works?  The format patch it generates is something like this

```
git format-patch -k --stdout --full-index --cherry-pick --right-only --src-prefix=a/ --dst-prefix=b/ --no-renames --no-cover-letter BRANCH1...BRANCH2
```

Comment: You're right. My question is hard to understand. I believe I even made mistakes explaining the algorithm. What does you answer do?

Comment: It's what `git rebase` calls to get a list of patches to apply, which is what it sounded like you were after